# Setting up a static IP, but for whatever reason when I load the openvpn file to a router it doesn't load the static IP I set

Tags: openvpn, router, static-ip

(Static IP is not one reserved by the access server)

Pics here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsZxi.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Just follow [this guide](https://www.itsfullofstars.de/2018/09/openvpn-assign-static-ip-to-client/) then fix the ccd directory permission.

Make sure to check all the permissions on the said directory.